# Basic sort, with annoying bug

Tags: code-golf, array, random, integer

Your input is a list/sequence/vector/array of 5-255 positive integers, not necessarily unique.  You may assume whatever input format is most suitable, and that each integer (as well as the quantity of integers) is chosen uniformly at random from the range 5-255.

The goal is to output the same list, in the same (or equivalent) format, but sorted into increasing (nondecreasing) order. A common early exercise in learning a language.  Submissions to include:

1. An answer which works correctly and achieves the goal; and
2. A second answer which contains an annoying bug.  Between 1% and 10% of the time, the output needs to be a list in the correct format and containing the correct elements, but *in the wrong order* (any order except correctly sorted).  The rest of the time, the program must work correctly and achieve the goal.

The two answers must have [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) one; that is, we can get one from the other by deleting one byte, or adding one byte, or changing one byte.

Scoring as usual in code-golf (based on the shorter of your two answers), with usual loopholes forbidden.

10% bonus (decrease to score) if the annoying bug is input-independent, i.e. using the same input again doesn't reproduce the bug (except between 1% and 10% of the time).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I suggest removing the bonus, it’s not really good practice.

Comment: It seems that an answer that simply doesn't distinguish between two of the values (say, it can't tell 5 apart from 6, so it leaves 5s and 6s in the order they were given) fails with probability approximately 10.8%, which is just over the threshold.

Comment: It's unclear what is the probability of each possible input length.

Comment: Should the bugged program work correctly 1-10% of the time for each individual length, or is the length of the input also chosen at random? If it is, what is the distribution?

Comment: Should the spec _between 1% and 10%_ of the time be fulfilled for _each_ input or just _overall_ for the set of possible inputs? For some inputs like `[5,5,5]` it's impossible to produce the wrong order

Comment: There's a subtlety regarding our [default IO formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/20260). If our code defines a function, is it OK if it has some chance of defining the function consistently buggy, as opposed to defining a function that has some chance of being buggy?

Comment: @LuisMendo, overall -- that's why I specified the probabilities as I did.

Comment: @Zgarb, the input length is 5-255, chosen uniformly at random.

Comment: @xnor, I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  If I run your code on the input (as specified, with random integers of random length), I should get buggy output between 1% and 10% of the time.

Comment: @VadimPonomarenko On this site people are allowed to provide functions as well as full programs. _xnor_ is asking whether it is allowed to have a function that, 1% to 10% of the time when created, is a buggy function that will always have a bug. Keeping to the letter of your question the answer's probably _no_, but it would be more fun if it was _yes_.

Comment: @wizzwizz, the purpose of the challenge is to simulate a programmer trying to track down an intermittent bug.  If the buggy function always produces the wrong answer, then the bug is not intermittent.

Comment: @VadimPonomarenko I'm making a distinction between the function object that exists in the memory of the interpreter / program and the textual representation of code that creates the function. 1% to 10% of the time that the textual representation of code is evaluated, the function created will always have a bug. The rest of the time, the function created will not have the bug. Is this clearer?

Comment: @wizzwizz4, the transitory storage of the function object in memory is immaterial to this challenge.  What matters is usage of the code on data sets.  If I evaluate the code, and run it on 1000 data sets, I should get (roughly) 10-100 wrong outputs.  If instead there is a 5% chance of getting 1000 wrong outputs, then the bug is not intermittent.

Comment: It depends how you're doing it. If you are using something like Python's `timeit` with both the function definition and parameters, it would give you roughly 10-100 wrong outputs.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, if it gives 10-100 wrong outputs (1%-10% on average) then it is a valid submission.

Comment: But it depends how you test it. (cc: @xnor) I recommend allowing this since in most languages it won't shorten the program, but in languages where it's golfy it'll make it more interesting. But it's up to you as the OP.

Comment: If you choose to accept an answer, you should accept the answer that wins by the winning criteria (here: lowest score).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

### Bug-free version, 37 bytes

```python
lambda l:sorted(l,reverse=l[-9:]==[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwEETv@Yq1pwRrrUoPBnLxN2qRaFMNpEnZpoKI3x4TK3jxtLAzb2aGh785uwudOAYj@3MrwfDRoVctNTmqu8JRCVOv9rwRom5Y0P0QZUBpW9eTi5usBwElIZ1D0KBtkq6KbsqScQImivVsLtLR1tMq31YVgwScfsBfE2sIYIzoqGEE5raliK@FgO9MZIQMmJDsMF05PF/r2J0VMb6Xnn4YxsIb)

### Annoying version, 36 bytes

```python
lambda l:sorted(l,reverse=l[9:]==[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCsIwEITv@xRrTwmWWpUeDOTia9Qi0aY1kJ@SpoKIzx5TK3jxtLAz38wMj3Bzdh87fopamEsrULPR@SBbonMv79KPkuv6wBrO64ZGZYakohe2dQaubrIBOZYAnfOoUNlZ6iXZliVlgDqJ9WIu5qNsIFW@qyqKM3D@AX9NtAH0KaIjmgIubWueXiuO35WeAgx@RrLj1DN8vjapOytSvBGBfBhK4xs)

This depends on the input and therefore does not qualify for the bonus.
It has a probability of around 2% to fail. It fails when the input length is lower then 10.

Combined with [LyricLy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147094/64121) this gets 34 bytes:

```python
lambda l:sorted(l)[::l[9:]>[]or 1]
lambda l:sorted(l)[::l[9:]>[]or-1]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the space in the bug-free version.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 without the space `or1` will get interpreted as an variable name and raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5*0.9 = 4.5 bytes

**Working solution**

```
{TLΩi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9oYOD2vzrE59zKzP@1Ov@jjXTMzHWMjXTMdQyNjHVMTICUjmksAA)

**Explanation**

```
{      # sort input
 TL    # push the range [1 ... 10]
   Ω   # pick a random number in the range
    i  # if true (equal to 1), do nothing
```

**Solution containing the bug**

Gives the wrong solution 10% of the time (independent on input).

```
{TLΩiR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9oYOD2vzrE59zKzKD/tTr/o410zMx1jI10zHUMjYx1TEyAlI5pLAA)

**Explanation**

Same as the working solution, except it reverses the list if the number picked is true.

Comment: Seriously what the hey. Output isn't even of the right cardinality.

Comment: @Joshua What do you mean?

Comment: Try it online shows it outputting a list of lists.

Comment: @Joshua The TiO link includes a header `100F` and a footer `},` that help us visualize the result of the function called on the input multiple times. This shows us that the working solution always returns correct results, whilst the bugged one has flawed output .

Comment: Please, someone, explain the algorithm.  Soon I will accept the top-ranked submission (or one of the top-ranked submissions).  I can't accept any solution which I can't understand.

Comment: @VadimPonomarenko: Added an explanation

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 * (100% - 10%) = 6.3 bytes

```
Ṣ¹⁵X:¤¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkWHdj5q3BphdWjJoYX/wx/u6j6x3ehwu7fKo6Y1kf//R1vqKBjqKBjpKBgDGQYGQKY5iGVqEAsA)

Buggy version:

```
ṢẊ⁵X:¤¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd3U9atwaYXVoyaGF/8Mf7uo@sd3ocLu3yqOmNZH//0db6igY6igY6SgYAxkGBkCmOYhlahALAA)

In both links, there's a test harness that will run the code 100 times, each time with the list you give as the argument, and then return the results.

The probability of each input length is:

```
0.1 - 0.1/(length!)
```

So for length 1 there's a 0% probability, for length 2 5%, for length 3 8.83̅%, for length 4 9.583̅% etc. until length ∞ which has a 10% probability.

Comment: Should be `0.1 - 0.1/(length!)`.

Comment: @user202729 sure

Comment: `Ṣ⁵X’¤¡` and `Ṣ⁵X¤¡` should works too: buggy version return the list unsorted <10% of the time, and given that the input is chosen uniformly random, it should work, save 2 bytes.

Comment: If you don't like that solution you can obviously just delete the `¹` to save 1 byte (the rule count number of byte = the shorter one) ; also there is an extraneous combining overline after the second `6` in `6.6̅%`.

Comment: @user202729 Unfortunately then it won't be input-independent anymore, and no I can't "just remove the `¹`" because then it wouldn't sort at all 10% of the time.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, score <s>58</s> 57 - 10% = 51.3

Saved a byte thanks to ovs.

#### Bug-free version, 57 bytes

```python
lambda m:sorted(m)[::random()>.1or 1]
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHXqji/qCQ1RSNXM9rKqigxLyU/V0PTTs8wv0jXMJYrrSg/VwEiqpCZWwBUqvW/oCgzr0QjTSPaUEfBREfBXEfBCMiI1dT8DwA)

#### Bugged version, 57 bytes

```python
lambda m:sorted(m)[::random()>.1or-1]
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHXqji/qCQ1RSNXM9rKqigxLyU/V0PTTs8wv0jBMJYrrSg/VwEiqpCZWwBUqvW/oCgzr0QjTSPaUEfBREfBXEfBCMiI1dT8DwA)

I decided to try a solution that uses the bonus. It doesn't beat the other Python answer, but I had fun thinking it up.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 71*0.9 = 63.9 bytes

**Bug-free:**

```
c(int*a,int*b){return*a-*b;}f(a,n)int*a;{if(rand()%1<9)qsort(a,n,4,c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDBaoNAFLz7FYMQ2GdW0LSRtqv00l4baHMLOZhVyx6iVje9iN9udzdioRD6Dg9mZ9/MeyPDTymnSTJV6yDntp9o6Ep96eogD4OTGCuW85ocLwZVsS6vC0arOH2kr77ptKX5PZckxum7UQV02WtG3uDBlJmDPsTJUThYNR2sF1QWCag0TgTWa0WOtKUP6ogMW6wxG222kfCuw0xzxAnN0MrILOJojdb/6sPi0XbmT8X81V0BnztLEgurKjC3RYqWzLj8pdrMElc8ut5edM8knuEjxNtuj4/d@/71xceTe5mRUR89zy52zlW9ZNO7C7U6lywiunHC5uFvQi5eozj9AA)

**Buggy:**

```
c(int*a,int*b){return*a-*b;}f(a,n)int*a;{if(rand()%10<9)qsort(a,n,4,c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDBaoNAFLz7FYMQ2GdW0LSRtqv00l4baHMLOZhVyx6iVje9iN9udzdioRD6Dg9mZ9/MeyPDTymnSTJV6yDntp9o6Ep96eogD4OTGCuW85ocLwZVsS6vC0arOEof6atvOm15fs8liXH6blQBXfaakTd4MGUGoQ9xchQOVk0HawaVRQIqjROB9VqRI23pgzoiwxZrzE6bbSS86zDTHHFCM7QyMos4WqP1v/qweLSd@VMxf3VXwOfOksTCqgrMbZGiJTMuf6k2s8QVj663F90ziWf4CPG22@Nj975/ffHx5F5mZNRHz7OLnXNVL9n07kKtziWLiG6csHn4m5CL1yhOPw)

Comment: +1 for %1 (oh come on 6 more to go you gotta be kidding me)

Answer (score 4):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 31 bytes

**Bugged solution:**

```
{a->a.sort()[a[9]?0..-1:-1..0]}
```

**Working solution:**

```
{a->a.sort()[a[0]?0..-1:-1..0]}
```

The Groovy subscript operator (the `getAt` method) returns null for lists if the index is bigger than the size. So if there's a ninth element it'll stay the same as the sorted list, but if not (1.99203187% chance) it'll be reversed. However there will always be a first element because the list's size is always bigger than or equal to 5. So the 0 in `a[0]` could be swapped with 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first post!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), score 8 * 0.9 = 7.2

First snippet (correct one):

```
h.uSNT.S
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h.uSNT.S&input=%5B1%2C5%2C3%2C9%2C2%5D&debug=0)**

Second snippet (bugged one):

```
O.uSNT.S
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=O.uSNT.S&input=%5B1%2C5%2C3%2C9%2C2%5D&debug=0)**

Saved two bytes (and 1.8 score) thanks to [isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg)!

Comment: I think 9 rather than 10 new copies would be fine. The possibility of `.S` returning the input unchanged means that in those (rare) cases, our chances of getting the wrong answer drop from 10% to 0% - so on average, it's still in the right range. Of course, 10 copies are fine too.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have made a mistake in my explanation, now addressed. I said *`.S` might also return the input itself* (which wouldn't be a problem), but I meant *`.S` might also return the sorted list*.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant too.

Comment: Same idea, but shorter: `O.uSNT.S`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

This is 26.1 bytes with the bonus, but I'm not entirely sure I earn the bonus; on already-sorted input, both versions always produce sorted output.

### Bug-free version (29 bytes)

```
If[RandomReal[]<0.,#,Sort@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8zLTooMS8lPzcoNTEnOtbGQE9HWSc4v6jEQTlW7T9UzjOvJDU9tSi62lTHyNS0VgeraCwQ/AcA)

### Annoying version (30 bytes)

```
If[RandomReal[]<0.1,#,Sort@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8zLTooMS8lPzcoNTEnOtbGQM9QR1knOL@oxEE5Vu0/VNIzryQ1PbUoutpUx8jUtFYHq2gsEPwHAA)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 70 bytes

### Bug-free version, 70 bytes

```
<?unset($argv[0]);((rand(1,9)?"":r).sort)($argv);echo join(" ",$argv);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr40rzi1REMlsSi9LNogVtNaQ6MoMS9Fw1DHUtNeScmqSFOvOL@oRBOiQtM6NTkjXyErPzNPQ0lBSQcq@P//fyPT/4Zm/02BNJBhavjf2Oy/pSVQ6F9@QUlmfl7xf908AA)

### Bugged version, 70 bytes

```
<?unset($argv[0]);((rand(0,9)?"":r).sort)($argv);echo join(" ",$argv);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr40rzi1REMlsSi9LNogVtNaQ6MoMS9Fw0DHUtNeScmqSFOvOL@oRBOiQtM6NTkjXyErPzNPQ0lBSQcq@P//fyPT/4Zm/02BNJBhavjf2Oy/pSVQ6F9@QUlmfl7xf908AA)

The bugged version sorts in reverse order 10% of the time (based on a random number generator).

Comment: no need for the tag with `-r` (-2 bytes). join by underscore; that should be equivalent (-2 bytes). use `asort` instead of `sort` (-1 byte).

Comment: ... or use the whole word instead of prefix (or not): `unset($argv[0]);(rand(1,9)?sort:rsort)($argv);echo join(_,$argv);` (also 65 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

Buggy:

```python
lambda l:l[9:]and l.sort()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKifa0io2MS9FIUevOL@oREPzf1p@kUKOQmaeQnS0sY6hjpGOaaxOUWJeeqqGkYGOriEQacZacXEWFGXmlSjkcHGmaeRowrk66jF56v8B)

Outputs by [modifying the input list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/20260).  Sorts the list only if its length is at least 10. The non-buggy version replaces the `9` with a `0` to always sort.

Working:

```python
lambda l:l[0:]and l.sort()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcexCoAgEADQub7ithSuKKNF6EvMwSgruM4wl77emoK3vOtJe2CV/Thlcue8OCBNptXW8QLU3CEmIbMPEQgOBmN67FDhYDE63lahWqy7j7S6LK54cAIqCy9I/sVq4iq/)

We can modify the function to return the list at the cost of 4 bytes, for 30 bytes total:

```python
lambda l:l[9:]and l.sort()or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcRBCoAgEADAc71ijwpblNEhoZeYB6OsYFvDvPR6KxjmetIeWGU/TpncOS8OSJMZtHW8ANV3iEnIEIGy/4eDwZgOW1TYW4yOt1WoBqv2I60uiysenMALkvkF)

---

25 bytes with some stretches of the rules:

```python
[list,sorted][id(0)%17>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPzons7hEpzi/qCQ1JTY6M0XDQFPV0NzOIPZ/QVFmXolCmka0sY6hjlGs5n8A)

Outputs a function literal that either sorts or is the identity, using `id(0)` as a random source. Change `>` to `>=` to fix, or `0` to `~0`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

Buggy version:

```
?OIV¦9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYuxDYAwEAMXcvH@hORTUVPR0SB6JErESgzCYo8r27rz@dxX5rwu2/eOzNydAVoDo4MVQbCrdYPXArKjNLhpTqbp4Ai0gAs2yaYcqOJFN5vAIod2/A)

Correct version:

```
?OIVK9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsrDoBAEEMvVDGd/c0qNEHgMARPgiScf6hqm/d6f@@Tuezrsc3MPJ0BWgdjgBVBcKgNg9cCcqB0uGk203RwBnrABbtkU05U8aKbNbDIoV0/)

### Explanation

These programs are completely deterministic.
In fact, Husk has currently no support at all for random numbers.

```
?  V    If any element
    ¦9  is divisible by 9 (in buggy version),
    K9  is truthy when replaced by 9 (in correct version),
 O      sort the list,
  I     otherwise return it unchanged.
```

I claim that the output of the buggy program is not sorted with a probability between 1% and 2%.
Denote by **N = 251** the number of possible values of the elements.
The probability that a random list of length **L** contains no multiples of 9 is **((N-K)/N)^L**, where **K** is the number of values divisible by 9 (in our case **K = 28**).
The total probability is the average of this for **5 ≤ L ≤ 255**, which is about 1.98%.
Some of these lists are false positives, since they are already sorted.
The probability of a random list of length **L** to be sorted is at most **((N+N*(N-1)/2)/N^2)^⌊L/2⌋**: if we break the list into chunks of length 2, each of the **⌊L/2⌋** chunks must be sorted.
The total probability of a list being sorted is bounded by the average of the above for **5 ≤ L ≤ 255**, which is about 0.30%.
Thus the probability of the function returning a non-sorted list is between 1.67% and 1.98%.

Comment: divisible by 9 gives approx 11% chance of failure. and not sorting doesn´t guarantee that the list is unsorted.

Comment: @Titus I address this in the analysis. Failure to sort occurs only if the list contains _no_ elements that are divisible by 9. The probability of this is about 1.98%. And it's true that if the list is already sorted, doing nothing will also give a sorted list. However, the probability of the list being already sorted is at most 0.30%, which is low enough that the total probability of outputting an unsorted list is above 1%.

Comment: true ... and the input being sorted doesn´t change the bug.

Comment: Could you maybe use `↓9` instead of `V¦9`, and shorten it to just `9` for the correct version? This would make it always fail on short inputs and always work correcly on longer ones, but since the input length follows a random distribution it should still be a valid answer

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26 bytes

### Correct version

```bash
s=n
sort -${s:RANDOM%20<0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2j6s4v6hEQVelutgqyNHPxd9X1dDAxqD2/39LLkMuIy5jIDQ0MOAyMgfSpgYA) or [check the probabilities](https://tio.run/##Jc7BCoJAGATg@/8UP2qoiLQaEVoGQdcKumal6ZYe2s3d9dT27LYWc5jLBzO3UjZDxXumsogQAlWp1oo@X3DnAq/YMiwk7dD5kWKJNUdDcCTaG2TGQHKhMHTeMj1u9tvDbhKTFfkMvlYC3Zy5aAK0ajjUnFE9ct2ztsOw0pLWGAq0pH3BwDuRMDkHPgZ2Hk3/iynaD2tIIIIYZibmI8QL03PyBQ).

### Bugged version

```bash
s=n
sort -${s:RANDOM%20<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2j6s4v6hEQVelutgqyNHPxd9X1cjAxrD2/39LLkMuIy5jIDQ0MOAyMgfSpgYA) or [check the probabilities](https://tio.run/##Jc7BCoJAGATg@/8UP2qoiLQaEVoGQdcKumal6ZYe2s3d9dT27LYWc5jLBzO3UjZDxXumsogQAlWp1oo@X3DnAq/YMiwk7dD5kWKJNUdDcCTaG2TGQHKhMHTeMj1u9tvDbhKTVfQZfK0Eujlz0QRo1XCoOaN65LpnbYdhpSWtMRRoSfuCgXciYXIOfAzsPJr@F1O0H9aQQAQxzEzMR4gXpufkCw).

Takes input as newline-separated numbers. Uses the builtin variable `RANDOM`, which [always returns a (pseudo)random number in the range 0 - 32767](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html). Using `%20` results in about a 5% failure rate (thanks @Titus for clarifying issues with `%10`).

This randomness means the failure rate is independent of the input, but this does require that the input array includes at least one number with more than one digit, because the failure output is sorted lexicographically.

### Alternate version, 27 bytes

```bash
((RANDOM+20))||cat&&sort -n
```

Bugged version replaces the `+` with a `%`. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##JY6xCsIwGIT3PMWPlTYhBNOKSBUFwVUFV6u2ptF2MLFJuuXda6rccMP3wd2jss0gdK/cJuWcI1G5rZPvD3pqA3doFZRWdjD9KeUaag1BgVHxeMD4vDvuTweacUK8DySOrTYOmBqIdwaSQiUQgqRoNKq1kn7kvldtB0x4K2tgBiY2ugHFF87yKyVAoyKd/SdXEL0mQ45SlKF5SDiJsmXoBf8C) or [try it bugged](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4IwHMXv@xR/tHRDRtOIsCgIulbQNStNV3poy23e9t3XLN7hHX4/eO9R6dbVchBmkzLGUF2ZreHvD3pKBXfoBJSa9zD5KeUaGglegVGx2GF83h33p8M0Y4RY60kUaakMUOGINQriQsTgg3jdStRIwe3I7SC6HmhtNW@AKgh0eIMEXxjNrwmBJCzS2X9yBeErcDlKUYbmPv4kypa@F@wL).

Comment: penny picking: `%10` has a higher chance of returning `0` to `7` than `8` or `9`, so the chance for failure is above 10% ;)

Comment: @Titus Thanks, I forgot about that fact. Updated to use `%20` like your answer does.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

Bug-free version (at least for integers in the range 0-2147483647, so anything in the given range):

```
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>a-b>>0)
```

Buggy version:

```
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>a-b>>1)
```

Depends on a) the engine's sorting algorithm and b) the input list containing two values in the wrong order that differ by 1. (If the probability of that turns out to be too low then the `1` can be increased, but by the time you get to `8` it simply won't sort anything in the range `5-255`.)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>7*0.9 = 6.3</s> 6*0.9 = 5.4 bytes

Buggy version:

```
Gr.9<?S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/371Iz9LGPvj//2hTHRMdYx0jHcNYAA)

**Explanation:**

```
G        % Grab input
 r       % Push a random number between 0 and 1
  .9     % Push 0.9
    <    % Check if the random number is smaller than 0.9
     ?   % If true
      S  % Sort input
         % Implicit output
```

Bug-free version:

```
Gr9<?S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P7hIz9LGPvj//2hTHRMdYx0jHcNYAA)

**Explanation:**

```
G       % Grab input
 r      % Push a random number between 0 and 1
  9     % Push 9
   <    % Check if the random number is smaller than 9 (always true)
    ?   % If true
     S  % Sort the input
        % Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 62 bytes

inspired by [Jo´s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147092/55735) (and I just noticed: it´s a port of [Justin Mariner´s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147112/55735)):

working (sorts ascending):

```php
unset($argv[0]);(r[rand()+20].sort)($argv);echo join(_,$argv);
```

buggy (approx. 5% chance of descending sort):

```php
unset($argv[0]);(r[rand()%20].sort)($argv);echo join(_,$argv);
```

Run with `-nr`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 9 bytes - 10% = 8.1

**Bugged Solution:**

```
g0TUn?};_
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/dICQ0z77WOv7////RhjoKpjoKJjoKxjoKZjoKhrEA)

**Working Solution:**

```
g1TUn?};_
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/dMCQ0z77WOv7////RhjoKpjoKJjoKxjoKZjoKhrEA)

The bugged code does the following:

```
g0TUn?};_

g          \ Sort the stack correctly
 0TU       \ Generate random(0, 10)
    n? ;   \ If this is zero:
      }    \    Cyclically shift the stack right once
        _  \ Print the result
```

The fixed code simply changes `0` to `1`. As `random(1, 10)` will never be `0`, the if statement will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 36*0.9 = 32.4 bytes

Buggy version:

```matlab
@(x)sort(x)(shift(1:end,+(rand<.1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCsAgDADArzgmVEIdXKRCvyLV0CxaVEp/nzrdcu2a6S3KkYj0hA9H63MB4xae4EKp2W7QU80HOURUbt2ImGhc8LvNMh7g9TyiXVd/)

Bug-free version:

```matlab
@(x)sort(x)(shift(1:end,+(rand<.0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCsAgDADArzgmVEIdXKRCvyLV0CxaVEp/nzrdcu2a6S3KkYj0hA9H63MB4xae4EKp2W7QU80H7Yio3LoRMdG44HebZTzA63lEu67@)

This sorts the vector, then shifts all numbers one to the right if a random number is less than 0.1.

Comment: Yes, you're of course right :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 42 bytes

Buggy

```
sort|if length%13<=0then reverse else. end
```

Working (delete the =)

```
sort|if length%13<0then reverse else. end
```

Assuming line lengths are uniform in range [5,255] about 7% will trigger the bug

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLjtowFN3zFUfASMlA3gRGDHxCN92mDDLEgTCJDbYzdCS@vfTGBqmLemXfx3lc39PlPsLpglJyDSENjuyLg2HX1Y1BLaCYKFF1Ym9qKaAlrhyd5jgac15GkZKaG8P2suShVIfoWn/W0U/qke1WdO2OKz06XQYjGIkDF1wxw5HEscWVLTGcOwOmFPvWkBUaLg7miDxI8xzXmq5frOlIm5Ny4C41KHkFwX@bbY@z/VHvSYiszHIAOmERb8A0xnvZCYMbBRIX0Ib4qeYGD16azOIkw@sj7GOCNM@SOEl8vICyi9lbNp@9YYRWlkg/ssS2Fg53kmCKcAovRIR5nmdzylWNlMrHBu9Wosq3pHb5P6lWVrbBGp4XFukmytLFfOG/pnl8cyiT/IlSMsM8x@pbi3X1MLdKYI5cgLdn891neKO5HQIdx@6Muxj5Hut@OhMKEbtvkw3TBs@CAorvO6W517PYUa4eJZbpAdrzOFZw2hCy/AQIC/eJwWPm4plo2dnrLUeR7fNpdGNB8X/tBYnvWxuifB8U8ZQwngW0NT5udy2VudXPTXlJstU6dsL4F20bt8rCHuDel4Xrdd/htA/l59ApH@5YiV9e6A9t5R957vdb34NAdE0T2LWkh2LXQHaGHn8B)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 22.5 bytes (25 bytes - 10%)

#### with bug:

```
[:]`(1&A.)@.(0.1>?@0:)/:~
```

#### without bug:

```
[:]`(0&A.)@.(0.1>?@0:)/:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6OtYhM0DNUc9TQd9DQM9Azt7B0MrDT1rer@a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3Hl5ccnlaYr2OopgPUZYNHHxZWanJGvoJGmZKigYWhgoGCsYqJgrGCkqWmtAdGOIfEfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30*.9 = 27 bytes

(buggy)

```r
function(l)sort(l,runif(1)<.1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHszi/qEQjR6eoNC8zTcNQ007PUPP/fwA)

(not buggy)

```r
function(l)sort(l,runif(1)<.0)
```

The buggy version sorts in `decreasing=T` 10% of the time, sampling from a uniform(0,1) distribution. The un-buggy version is always `decreasing=F`

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 42 bytes - 10% = 37.8

Bug-free:

```
{sort key={|i|currentTime|[_%20//19*0+i]}}
```

Buggy:

```
{sort key={|i|currentTime|[_%20//19*i+i]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1BDoIwFATQdTnFmOhGm0BBTTThFu4qUSJt/LFQbWFhKGfHkrj4m5l5@c429dzW1GFMmMa5xHUevXU9XupbjoHCY3BOdf2FWhXkbZNnaSpOW9pRNU0z8@oDwSGyDAHaOhAamzAmj/zA97zgORfVUsXzQwvt@1IuwXswBiYu34N/QoA0JAxWJaSIqIj4wI8VqoQ1tlN/Hp2jrsd9fUuXn7omo5p7Ms0/)

This uses the `currentTime` function to create random numbers. It seems that their distribution varies a little between machines. The ratio `20//19` can be adjusted to get different results for no byte penalty (unless it is smaller than `99//98`).

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>45</s> 34.2 (<s>50</s> 38 - 10%) bytes

**Normal version:**

```java
a->{if(Math.random()>0.)a.sort(null);}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZBPS8QwEMXv@ynmmFo2FEEv3S14FNw9uEfxMLbpmtqmJZlWlqWfvU7/KBXdipAEMnkv7zeTYYPrslImS966OEfnYIfanFcA2pCyKcYK9v0VoCl1ArHI2CJr0rm8sxZPD9rR5p61R2UjQC9kbcublyMkHcMeDGyhw3V01qnYIb1KiyYpC@FFgfRQutKSMHWee2HbhaO3ql9y9k5fDNEFg4kDWW2OT8@cNFIt4ow5fY0JYquQ1ONQmhRfFjFwAxgZi5lpqh5OjlQhy5pkxfH0Q9KuemSrGw74ZF4EW2b5b2dGvf@qjoRgWu/7zK@ubwLPv51aS0vba0BvgxD05rKeX31/IoNZvMQk@TumHU6rqLZmzj4Or@0@AA)

```java
a->{                    // Method with ArrayList<Integer> parameter and no return-type
  if(Math.random()>0.)  //  If the random 0-1 double is larger than 0:
    a.sort(null);       //   Sort the input-List
}                       // End of method
```

---

**Bugged version (<s>51</s> 39 bytes):**

```java
a->{if(Math.random()>0.1)a.sort(null);}
```

LD of 1: `1` added.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZBPT4QwEMXv@ynmWCTboIle2CXxaOLuwT0aD2MpaxEKKQNms@Gz4/BHg1ExJm2TTt/r@82k2OC6KLVN49dOZVhVsENjzysAY0m7BJWGfX8FaAoTgxIpW2RNJpO3zuHp3lS0uWPtUbsI0AtZ2/LmVRGSUbAHC1vocB2dTSJ2SC/SoY2LXHhRIC89lFXhSNg6y7yw7cLRXNbPGZunP4bsnMnEgZyxx8cnjhqxFnnGoL7GCMppJP0wlCbFp0UM4ABWKjEzTdXDqSKdy6ImWXI8fZO0qx7ZmYYDPpgXwZZZ/tuZ1W8/qiMhmNb7OvSLq@vA82@m1pLC9Row2yAEs/ldz6@@P5HBLF5iHP8d0w6n01Q7O2cfh9d27w)

```java
a->{                     // Method with ArrayList<Integer> parameter and no return-type
  if(Math.random()>0.1)  //  If the random 0-1 double is larger than 0.1:
    a.sort(null);        //   Sort the input-List
}                        // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, 25*0.9=22.5

```
new Date%25?x:x.sort()
```

input x